# Within 27 days from Serv_from_date we have to sum the serv_unit_cnt

Tags: sql, oracle

Input Data :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x07nW.png)

```
SN  SRC_MBR_ID  MEDCLM_KEY  CALENDAR_PROCESS_DATE   SERV_FROM_DATE  SERV_UNIT_CNT
5   022502303   32761925957 9/9/2017                8/23/2017       30.00
6   022502303   32791176170 9/19/2017               9/6/2017        30.00
7   022502303   32855914080 10/7/2017               9/20/2017       30.00
8   022502303   33301033608 2/9/2018                10/4/2017       30.00
9   022502303   33301033637 2/9/2018                10/4/2017       30.00
```

Expected output :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8YKD.png)

```
SN  SRC_MBR_ID  MEDCLM_KEY  CALENDAR_PROCESS_DATE   SERV_FROM_DATE  SERV_UNIT_CNT   sum_serv_unit_cnt
5   022502303   32761925957 9/9/2017                8/23/2017       30.00           30
6   022502303   32791176170 9/19/2017               9/6/2017        30.00           60
7   022502303   32855914080 10/7/2017               9/20/2017       30.00           30
8   022502303   33301033608 2/9/2018                10/4/2017       30.00           60
9   022502303   33301033637 2/9/2018                10/4/2017       30.00           90
```

results Entered :

> ---> sn - 5 serv_from_date is  8/23/2017 and serv_unit_cnt is 30. so sum_serv_unit is 30.
>
> ---> sn- 6 serv_from_date is 9/06/2017 and serv_unit_cnt is 30. as per 27 days from 1st row second row serv_from_date fall is 14 days so we
> have to sum The serv_unit_cnt is 60.
>
> ---> from 1st row serv_from_date to 3rd row days different is 29 so its not 27 days different from 1st row serv_from_date so
> sum_serv_unit_cnt is 30.
>
> ---> Once we break the 27 days again we need to consider new serv_from_date so i have considerd as 7th row serv_from_date. like wise we
> have to calculate.

Comment: Post your input and expected output as text and not images, take some time and write an explanation in plain English of your issue and preferable also post what you  have tried yourself.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT INL1.*,
                ceil(((INL1.SERV_FROM_DATE-INL1.MIN_SERV_FROM_DATE)+1)/28) ceil_cnt,
                 INL1.SERV_UNIT_CNT AS SERV_UN_CNT,
                sum(inl1.serv_uniT_cnt)  over  (partition by  inl1.src_mbr_id, 
               
                ROUND(((INL1.SERV_FROM_DATE-INL1.MIN_SERV_FROM_DATE)+1)/28)) sum_of_serv_unit_cnt
                  FROM (SELECT res.*,
                  MIN(res.SERV_FROM_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY res.SRC_MBR_ID) MIN_SERV_FROM_DATE
                  FROM TMP_QRY157929_KX

Comment: > Input data :  SN SRC_MBR_ID MEDCLM_KEY CALENDAR_PROCESS_DATE SERV_FROM_DATE SERV_UNIT_CNT 
5 022502303 32761925957 9/9/2017         8/23/2017 30.00         
6 022502303 32791176170 9/19/2017  9/6/2017 30.00 
7 022502303 32855914080 10/7/2017  9/20/2017 30.00 
8 022502303 33301033608 2/9/2018  10/4/2017 30.00 
9 022502303 33301033637 2/9/2018  10/4/2017 30.00

Comment: > output data  :SN SRC_MBR_ID MEDCLM_KEY CALENDAR_PROCESS_DATE SERV_FROM_DATE SERV_UNIT_CNT sum_serv_unit_cnt
5 022502303 32761925957 9/9/2017         8/23/2017 30.00   30        
6 022502303 32791176170 9/19/2017  9/6/2017 30.00   60
7 022502303 32855914080 10/7/2017  9/20/2017 30.00   30
8 022502303 33301033608 2/9/2018  10/4/2017 30.00   60 
9 022502303 33301033637 2/9/2018  10/4/2017 30.00   90

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the groups and then use window functions.  Use `lag()` to determine where groups start, a cumulative sum to define the group, and then the final sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(SERV_UNIT_CNT) over (partition by SRC_MBR_ID, grp order by SERV_FROM_DATE) as sum_serv_unit_cnt
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_sfd > SERV_FROM_DATE - 14 then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by SRC_MBR_ID order by SERV_FROM_DATE) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(SERV_FROM_DATE) over (partition by SRC_MBR_ID order by SERV_FROM_DATE) as prev_sfd
            from t
           ) t
      ) t;
```

Comment: Within 27 days from Serv_from_date we have to sum the serv_unit_cnt